# Amazon Pinpoint API vs AWS Simple Notification Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

For the purpose of sending push notifications from the backend, if we need a Push Notification Platform, could you please suggest which of these is intended for that purpose – Amazon SNS or Pinpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Both Amazon SNS and Amazon Pinpoint, supports sending push notification to various devices (e.g Android, iOS etc)

The major difference between Amazon SNS & Amazon Pinpoint is that :

*with Amazon SNS you have to set up your application to manage each message's audience, content, and delivery schedule. On the other hand, with Amazon Pinpoint you do not have to code these features, most of them are already built in. With Amazon Pinpoint, you can collect data about your app usage, create highly-targeted segments and send full campaigns(either immediate or scheduled) plus many more features.*